# What was the first QSO by an astronaut? Was it code or voice?

Tags: history

Discussion under [this answer to *Could amateur radio operators or others contact the ISS against NASA's wishes?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/51946/12102) in Space Exploration SE explore some activity from the Mir and ISS stations and the Space Shuttle, but I'm curious about the first proper Ham to Ham QSO by an astronaut *who was in space at the time.*

If an answer can cite known "firsts" for both code and for voice separately, that would be even better.

**update:** I just discovered that I'd asked three years ago a different but related question in Space Exploration SE. However, QSO's were not mentioned in the question or its answers.

- [First Ham Radio contact from space; what frequency, what kind of antenna, and how did they route the coax out the window?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49256/12102)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first vehicle that carried amateur radio onboard was the Space Shuttle. The [first QSO made from space](https://www.govtech.com/em/safety/ham-radio-is-a-link-to-earth-for-lonely-astronauts-at-the-space-station.html) was by Owen Garriott aboard the Space Shuttle Columbia in 1983. The transmission was voice.

While I can find some reference to contacting astronauts with CW, it seems pretty rare.

Comment: I just added a note to the end of the question post. I don't know if that contact and this one are the same or not.